# Encrypt Request Param in Client-Side JS, Decrypt Request Param in Java (Spring Controller)

Tags: javascript, java, spring, spring-mvc, encryption

I have a need to invoke a URL from the client-side (JS) with an encrypted parameter. Then I need to decrypt the URL from the server-side controller that it goes to.

Suppose I have
`window.location.href = "/app/submitted?docId=445";`

I need to encrypt the `docId=445` portion. I could use `atob/btoa` as

```
window.location.href = "/app/submitted?" + atob("docId=445"); // Whole Param
window.location.href = "/app/submitted?docId=" + atob("445"); // Just the value
```

I would prefer #1, but in both of those, when I come to my SpringMVC Controller, how would I pull and decrypt this param? Is there a Java encryption equivalent of `atob/btoa`?

```
@GetMapping("/app/submitted")
public ModelAndView  submitted(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, 
        @RequestParam("docId") Integer docId) {
      //...
      // How to decrypt here (either whole param or just the value) from an atob/btoa?

}
```

Or should I use encoding rather than encryption here, to guarantee equivalence on both tiers? My goal is to avoid displaying the ID anywhere in the address bar.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are asking for is base64 encoding/decoding on the server side - and yes Java most certainly can do that

```
@GetMapping("/app/submitted")
public ModelAndView  submitted(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, 
    @RequestParam("docId") String docId) {
  //...
  byte[] decodedDocIdBytes = Base64.getDecoder().decode(docId);
  String decodedDocIdAsString = new String(decoodDocIdBytes);

 }
```

Notice that docId has been changed to a String.

As a side note - base64 code is not encryption, so if you really want to keep the docId's secret, I'd look for another approach. If this is a REST(ish) API then the resource ID's (docIds) shouldn't have any external meaning, so there shouldn't be a requirement to hide them.